# svn and titling conflict?

Tags: packages, incompatibility, titling

Somehow there is a strange conflict with the `svn` package and the `titling` package. The following code gives me an error on TeXLive 2010 (but on an old TeX distribution at my work computer, it compiles just fine).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{svn}

\SVN $Date: 2011-05-06 20:57:26 +0100 (Fri, 06 May 2011) $
\date{\SVNDate}

\title{tesT}
\author{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

When I try to build it, I get hit with a problem with input stack size

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, pi
nyin, bulgarian, russian, ukrainian, ukenglish, usenglishmax, basque, french, l
oaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svn/svn.sty)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\GenericError ->\protect 
                         \GenericError  
l.6 \date{\SVNDate}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

The problem goes away if either

- I don't use the `titling` package
- If I don't actually use a real SVN Date. That is, if the SVN line is replaced by just `\SVN $Date$`

Any ideas? Any more information I should include? (I'm also not sure what tags to use for this question.)

---

*Edit* If I increase the `stack_size` in texmf.cnf, the error becomes

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=14000].
\PackageError #1#2#3->
                      \GenericError {(#1)\@spaces \@spaces \@spaces \@spaces...
l.6 \date{\SVNDate}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `svn` manual states in section 2.5 *Known Issues* the flexibility of `\SVNDate` to change its format e.g. when the language is changed does not allow its usage inside an expanded context (e.g. `\edef`). It is therefore defined to create an error message if it is used inside `\edef`. I'm personally not sure if this is a wise design decision. Defining `\SVNDate` as a robust macro would be a better idea.
Now the `titling` package uses `\protected@xdef` which seems to cause an endless loop while expanding the error message.

This error can be avoided by ensuring that `\SVNDate` isn't expanded by `\date`.
This can be done by the usual `\protect`, the plain `\noexpand` or, if this is required more often, by redefining `\SVNDate` to be robust:

```
\date{\noexpand\SVNDate}
% or
\date{\protect\SVNDate}
% or
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\SVNDate
\date{\SVNDate}
% or
\protected\expandafter\def\expandafter\SVNDate\expandafter{\SVNDate}
\date{\SVNDate}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `titling` redefines `\date` so it can be used again.  The redefinition is in the following code:

```
\appendiargdef{\date}{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}
    \renewcommand{\thanksmark}[1]{}
    \renewcommand{\thanksgap}[1]{}
    \protected@xdef\thedate{#1}
  \endgroup}
```

As a workaround, you could comment out this code although you would lose the reuse of date.)

Perhaps someone with more knowledge than me can propose an actual solution.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit more experimenting, apparently a sufficient work around is to protect the argument to the new `\date` command

```
 \date{\protect\SVNDate}
```

So far it works, but I don't know if it has any side-effects or if it is bad practice.